# sed regex is not working as expected

Tags: regex, sed

I am have a yaml file and it has the following text:

```
  /data/app0:
     server: x.y.z.p
     share: /data/app0
     mount: /data/app/0
```

And I want to have the following output:

```
  /data/app0:
     server: x.y.z.p
     share: /data/app0
     mount: /data/app/0
     options: _netdev,noatime,nodiratime
```

I tried the following which is a simple regex expression used -i and a but it is throwing an error:

```
[user@jump nodes]$ cat test.yaml
  /data/app0:
     server: x.y.z.p
     share: /data/app0
     mount: /data/apps/0
  /data/app1:
     server: x.y.z.p
     share: /data/app1
     mount: /data/apps/1
  /data/app2:
     server: x.y.z.p
     share: /data/app2
     mount: /data/apps/2
  /data/app3:
     server: x.y.z.p
     share: /data/app3
     mount: /data/apps/3

[user@jump nodes]$ sed -i '/mount: /data/app/*/a \
options: _netdev,noatime,nodiratime \' test.yaml
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: extra characters after command
[user@jump nodes]$
```

No idea why it is going wrong ?

Comment: `/` is a special character for sed.  Maybe you can  escape the ones in `/data/app/` like `\/`?  Or you could, you know, use a YAML parser like in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Sed is using / as the delimiter, so it thinks your search pattern is `/mount :/`.  So your command is `d` (delete) and the extra character (character 11) is the first `a` in `data`.  Escape the path slashes with backslashes.  And I don't think you should escape the last single-quote:

```
[user@jump nodes]$ sed -i '/mount: \/data\/app\/*/a \
options: _netdev,noatime,nodiratime' test.yaml
```

Comment: [user@jump nodes]$ sed -i '/mount: \/data\/app*/*/a \
options: _netdev,noatime,nodiratime' test.yaml
sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unknown command: `*'
[user@jump nodes]$

Comment: @learner: Jack‘s command spans over two lines **with a line break**.

Comment: Need a backslash in `app*\/*`.  With what you have, it thinks the search pattern is `/mount: \/data\/app*/` and the command is `*`.

Comment: Why not just use `/mount/`?